# Import custom stylesheets for IE8 or lower

Tags: joomla-3.x, css

I use a responsive template which works great on most browsers, but on some older browsers like IE8 some elements doesn't display correctly, so I wanted to create a custom CSS file for Internet Explorer.

How can I import IE-Only stylesheets the proper way? I could add a condition like  `<!--[if lt IE9]> ... <![endif]-->` directly in the template but I don't know if there's a better solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: IE8 is Gone the Way of the Dodo, So Why Support a Dying Species?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my supervisor wants a IE8 compatible website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I added this code near the beginning of my index.php file (located in my template folder).

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$stylelink = '<!--[if lte IE 8]>' ."\n";
$stylelink .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="linkOfTheCSSFile/ie7.css" type="text/css"/>' ."\n";
$stylelink .= '<![endif]-->' ."\n";

$doc->addCustomTag($stylelink);
```

It works great for me.

Comment: Why not adding your code directly in html head section instead of using php?